# Facebook Login completely server side

Tags: node.js, facebook, oauth, ussd

The goal is to build a Facebook USSD platform. Completely server side. Allowing the user to log in and then create a facebook post, see their feed, etc.

I know there are companies in the world that is doing this and its working fine (u2opia mobile being one of them). However how on earth to log a user into Facebook and get an access token for them without OAuth? I cannot seem to find any help online to log a user in completely on server side with NodeJS. Do these companies have a special arrangement with Facebook in order to log in users without OAuth and Internet?

Is it at all possible in 2018 to log in a User into Facebook completely server side? I am just finding a lot of old posts from 2012 and 2014.

Comment: No clue what you're talking about. Getting a user access token requires user interaction, no way around that. The "server-side login flow" (that of course can be implemented using node as well) redirects the user to Facebook in their browser, and then back to the app URL. If you see any service implement a different form of login - then you should _describe_ it to us (and not expect that people have heard of whatever obscure service you might mention by name, or that they even go and create an account there to find out for you.)

Comment: Note however that asking users for their Facebook login credentials is strictly forbidden. If you see any service doing that, then you should stop wondering "how are they performing login with that", and _report them to Facebook_ instead.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to log a user in completely server side. You can build an implementation manually with browser redirects. Facebook has a tutorial on this. Their page states:

> if you need to implement browser-based login for an app without using our SDKs, such as in a webview for a native desktop app (for example Windows 8), or a login flow using entirely server-side code, you can build a Login flow for yourself by using browser redirects.

Here is the tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/